# Get Gizmos position in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I'm facing the problem with defining the center of the gameObject. In Unity it gives me the point which is not in the center, but Gizmos are located correctly. So maybe somebody knows how to get Gizmos coordinates?

3D model was imported by PiXYZ Plugin, and all the parts are messed up with different rotations, etc. The white sphere on the picture below shows the center of the selected gameObject found by the gameObject.position, but it is not what is needed.

[image]

#### UPD:

Now I figured out, that the pivot center points are located in the wrong positions (by switching editor mode), it comes from NX (CAD software) because objects of the model were moved by transformations. I can't do anything about it. So I found the script - http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=SetPivot, but it doesn't work well with rotated objects, which in my case is essential.

So now my question could be - "How to move the pivot point to the visual object center?".

I've tried to play with hierarchy, adding empty objects as parents, etc. Doesn't help with both local and global positions.

[image: Here is the same part, but Gizmos now are in the pivot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

## Use [`renderer.bounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html)

Any `Renderer` components will automatically calculate their axis-aligned bounding box, which you can use to estimate the visual center of the object:

```
Vector3 center = GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.center;
```

## Use [`collider.bounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-bounds.html)

Any `Renderer` components will automatically calculate their axis-aligned bounding box, which you can use to estimate the physical center of the object:

```
Vector3 center = GetComponent<Collider>().collider.bounds.center;
```

## Use transform hierarchy

Everything in your scene is positioned according to its `Transform` component, which keeps track of a world position (relative to the scene) and a local position (relative to its parent `Transform`). It is sometimes useful to re-parent one Transform to another one so that it's easier to manipulate them, or easier to calculate offsets between them.

Depending on what you need to do, you could attach an empty GameObject as a child, and use the position of that GameObject as your designated point.

## Use some other offset

Finally, don't forget that you can always manually assign some `Vector3` offset to whatever position you're calculating. This is potentially a clumsy workaround, but it works in a pinch.

Comment: See question update. I've tried things you mention, but even if you add either Renderer or Collider, it goes to the pivot center...

Answer (score 0):

You could create an empty gameobject, place it in the center of your imported model, then drag your imported model to be a child of the empty GameObject. Then when wanting the center position, use the parent you just created.